# SyntaxError while trying to launch a pynodered server

Tags: python-3.x, syntax-error, node-red

I am trying to launch a simple python code as a node in node-red, I installed pynodered and made a .py file including the following code

```
from pynodered import node_red
@node_red(category="pyfuncs")
def lower_case(node, msg):
    msg['payload'] = str(msg['payload']).lower()
    return msg
```

I tried launching the pynodered server but I got a syntax error (I tried on windows10/Ubuntu16.04 still the same error)

```
C:\Users\omara\Downloads\Cyber Physical Systems>pynodered test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\omara\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\runpy.py", line 170, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\users\omara\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\omara\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\Scripts\pynodered.exe\__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "c:\users\omara\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\pynodered\server.py", line 93
    print(f"From {name} register {obj.name}")
                                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```